# Flutter - rebuild GestureDetector widget without user interaction

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate, gesturedetector, user-interaction

I am trying to display 3 images one after another by using `GestureDetector` and its `onTap` method but one image should be displayed without tapping. Supposing I have three images **1.png**, **2.png**, **3.png** I would like to display the first image **1.png** at the first place. Clicking on it will result in displaying the second image **2.png**.
The second image **2.png** should now be replaced after x seconds by displaying the image **3.png**.

I am using a stateful widget that stores which image is currently shown. For the first image change the `onTap` will execute `setState( () {screen = "2.png"}` and the widget is rebuilt. However, I am pretty stuck now when the third image should be displayed after x seconds delay because there should not be any user interaction and I am not sure where to change it. I tried a lot of stuff especially editting the state from outside the widget but I did not succeed til now.

This is the code I am using:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: MyScreen(),
  ));
}

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  String currentScreen = 'assets/images/1.png';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Container(
          child: Image.asset(currentScreen),
        ),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        if (currentScreen == 'assets/images/1.png') {
          setState(() {
            currentScreen = 'assets/images/2.png';
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Displaying the second image worked without any issues but I have no idea what/where to code in order to display the third image.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want the second and third picture to respond to the gesture detection. Try this, please.

```
 onTap: () {
        if (currentScreen == 'assets/images/1.png') {
          setState(() {
            currentScreen = 'assets/images/2.png';
          });

          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
            setState(() {
              currentScreen = 'assets/images/3.png';
            });
          });
        } else {
          return;
        }
      },
```

Comment: Hi, this worked for me. If I understood it correctly, you are changing the state to 'assets/images/2.png' which cause to not enter the if branch in the next build process but showing the image. However, you fired an async setState from the first onTap() which causes to set the state to 'assets/images/3.png' after the delay (?)

Comment: @Akkamar Yes, exactly! You can play around with the conditions based on what you want. I just assumed that you didn't want the second and third image to respond to the onTap callback and excluded them out of the callback so that it doesn't break the UI even if the user taps on the second and third image. Glad to be of some help.